# Fanless fiber channel switch?

Tags: hardware, fiber

I'm looking for a fanless (or a very quiet) fiber channel switch for my home office. The speed requirements are low: 2 Gbit per port, max 4-6 Gbit total throughput, 8 ports - more than enough. More quiet/less power consumption = better for me.

FC-hardware vendors never write a noise level ratio on their products so I'm asking you to share your personal experience with these devices. I prefer Qlogic because I have an experience with their products but any other vendor could be possible.

Comment: Fiber Channel kit simply isn't specced for SOHO applications. What you're attempting to achieve just seems like a bad fit.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there are any "fanless" Fibre switches out there.  They aren't exactly "home" type equipment.  But you could get a little brocade 300 which is small and power efficient if it's power that's the concern.  If it's noise, then put it in the garage or basement and run the fibre cables.  I suppose you could always disconnect the fans but that's up to you.